# Parsing list of list of ints with overlapping separators purescript-string-parsers

Tags: purescript

Let me use this example:

```
1 2 3 / 4 5 6
```

should parse into:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

So I write:

```
p1 :: Parser (List Char)
p1 = sepBy anyDigit (char ' ')

p2 :: Parser (List (List Char))
p2 = sepBy p1 (string " / ")
```

Alas, this fails:

```
(Left Character '/' is not a digit)
```

Which way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the separator `/` starts with a space, so the first parser is committing to parsing its separator and then the next digit.

You have a few options. You could change `p1` so that it explicitly looks for a space and not an operator:

```
sepBy anyDigit (char ' ' <* notFollowedBy (char '/'))
```

Alternatively, have your lexemes eagerly consume any trailing whitespace:

```
myDigit = anyDigit <* many whitespace

p1 = many1 myDigit
p2 = sepBy p1 (char '/' <* many whitespace)
```

Another option is to split your parser into an initial lexing phase, which splits the input into lexemes, removing whitespace. Then you wouldn't be able to use `string-parsers`, but `purescript-parsing` would be able to work on the stream of tokens.

Comment: Getting `Maximum call stack size exceeded` using 2nd eating trailing whitespace option.

Comment: Ah, I think that might be because `whitespace` succeeds on an empty string, so `many whitspace` will loop. You could try `many (char ' ')` instead.